# How do I get the dropdown that called my OnListener handler?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an array of 13 dropdown boxes, each attached to an event in my game. I have AddListener events attached to each, but they all call the same routine. In the routine, how can I determine from which dropdown object it was called?

Thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SelectSounds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMPro.TMP_Dropdown[] dropdownSFX = new TMPro.TMP_Dropdown[13];
    public Toggle[] soundToggles = new Toggle[13];

    void Awake()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        var temp = i;

        dropdownSFX[i].onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { DropdownValueChanged(temp); }); // This works fine on value change

        dropdownSFX[i].OnPointerClick.AddListener(delegate { DropdownValueChanged(temp); });
 // Gets error: TMP_Dropdown.OnPointerClick(PointerEventData)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context
    }

    private void DropdownValueChanged(int newPosition)
    {

    // Get the value of the dropdown, and from which dropdown it came?
        Debug.Log("In DropdownVC: " + newPosition);
        lastSelected = newPosition;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a method which takes a `DropDown` parameter.

```cs
public void DropdownValueChanged(Dropdown dropDown)
{
   Debug.Log(dropDown.value);                          // Gives the index of the selected item
   Debug.Log(dropDown.options[dropDown.value].text);   // Gives the text of the selected item
}
```

This method will give you the reference to the `DropDown`. And you can access to its value as I show in the method.

Now subscribe to the `OnValueChanged` as the following

[image]

At the very end of the picture, you can add reference to `DropDown`, and it will be passed to the method when called. Drag and drop the component to the circled zone :

[image]

Comment: I believe that would require adding references to all 13 dropdowns. I found what I needed and changed my code shown above. This works fine if I change the selected item in the dropdown. However, I would also like to execute the same routine if I simply click on the dropdown box, which selects it but doesn't trigger the onValueChanged event. The dropdown has an OnPointerClick method which might work for me, but I'm getting the compiler error shown in the comment in the code block above.

Comment: @RT2010 As the error says `OnPointerClick` is a method not an `event` where you can subscribe callbacks to and especially not a `UnityEvent` where you could `AddListener` ... I'ld say this answer is already as close as you can get .. I hope it wasn't you who downvoted it ;) You already have a loop for adding the callbacks on runtime so actually you don't have to configure anything on the individual dropdowns yourself!

Comment: @Malphegal since OP adds the callback in a loop on runtime anyway he shouldn't configure anything in the `onValueChanged` via the Inspector .. otherwise it's called double